# Java 1 million index array of 1x3 arrays - memory and efficiency

Tags: java, performance, memory, arraylist

I am doing some coding practice during my free time using some coding challenges posted on AdventOfCode.com

Challenge #6 involves turning 1 million (virtual) lights on and off with a set of hundreds of instructions. I find myself unable to even populate an ArrayList that is large enough to handle all of these "lights"

I decided to start the challenge by making a 1000x1000 array of 1x3 arrays which contain "x-coordinate" "y-coordinate" "on/off"

I have very limited experience with java efficiency (besides common sense) and I would greatly appreciate some direction.

Here is the challenge if you are interested: http://adventofcode.com/day/6

And here is my code so far, which sadly does not run past index ~7000 on my craptop (4gb RAM) - i do have a fancy desktop at home though.

I would appreciate some guidance regarding how to approach this problem with better memory and speed efficiency. I am a learning programmer and I will appreciate legitimately any guidance, whatever it may be. (Links/locations for learning are appreciated as well)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Day6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadFileClass myReaderClass = new ReadFileClass();
        ArrayList<String> allLines = myReaderClass.readFile("/C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Day6.txt");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> lightArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<=999999; i++){
            if(i%1000 ==0) System.out.println(i); //To see how fast/far the array populates
            int x;
            int y;
            String status = "off";
            for(int j = 0; j<=999; j++){
                x = j;
                y = i%999;
                ArrayList<Object> innerArray = new ArrayList<>();
                innerArray.add(x);
                innerArray.add(y);
                innerArray.add(status);
                lightArray.add(innerArray);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(lightArray); 
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**: I dunno what happened with the ArrayLists exactly (garbage accumulation maybe?) but I switched to a byte array and handle coordinate-->index conversions with a method now and I am smooth sailing. I'll post my final code once I'm finished fixing a small algorithm mistake (I misread the problem slightly). Thank you for your various suggestions!

**Edit 2**: My code works as intended now. Here it is, for anyone who is interested :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Day6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadFileExample myReaderClass = new ReadFileExample();
        ArrayList<String> allLines = myReaderClass.readFile("/C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Day6.txt");

        byte[] lightArray = new byte[1000000];

        for(int i = 0; i<=999999; i++){
            lightArray[i] = 0;
        }

        for(String s : allLines){           
            int x1, x2, y1, y2;
            int indexOfFirstNumber = -1;
            String nums = "0123456789";
            for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
                if(nums.indexOf(s.substring(i,i+1))!=-1){
                    indexOfFirstNumber = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int IOfirstComma = s.indexOf(",");
            int indexOfThrough = s.indexOf("through");
            int indexOfX2 = indexOfThrough+8;
            int IOsecondComma = s.indexOf(",", IOfirstComma+1);

            x1 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(indexOfFirstNumber, IOfirstComma));
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(IOfirstComma+1, s.indexOf(" ", IOfirstComma)));
            x2 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(indexOfX2, IOsecondComma));
            y2 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(IOsecondComma+1,s.length()));

            ArrayList<Integer> indexesToChange = coordinateRangeToIndexArray(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            if(s.substring(0,8).equals("turn off")){
                for(int i : indexesToChange){
                    lightArray[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            else if(s.substring(0,7).equals("turn on")){
                for(int i : indexesToChange){
                    lightArray[i] = 1;
                }
            }
            else if(s.substring(0,6).equals("toggle")){
                for(int i : indexesToChange){
                    if(lightArray[i] == 1){
                        lightArray[i] = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        lightArray[i] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error: Command not recognized");

            }
        }

        //calculate number of lights that are on
        int totalNumLightsOn = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<lightArray.length;i++){
            if(lightArray[i] == 1){
                totalNumLightsOn++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(totalNumLightsOn);
    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> coordinateRangeToIndexArray(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        //Given two coordinates, create an array of all the indexes the smallest possible rectangle encompasses
        final int ROW_SIZE = 1000;
        ArrayList<Integer> affectedIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int row = x1; row<=x2; row++){
            for(int column = y1; column<=y2; column++){
                affectedIndexes.add(column*ROW_SIZE+row+1);
            }
        }
        return affectedIndexes;
    }
}
```

Comment: When dealing with large data structures of known size, I would use simple arrays (not Lists). You'll save on processing and garbage collection: `ArrayLists` start out with size 16 and double on demand. Every time they double they replace their backing array - the old one needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: I would encapsulate the (x,y,onOff) data into a single object, then keep an array (not ArrayList) of those objects.

Comment: 1 million is not many.

Comment: "unable to even populate an ArrayList that is large enough" why, what happens when you try?

Comment: Explicitly storing xy coordinates is not needed. You either have them as array indexes in case of 2D arrays, or you can simply calculate them (divide by 1000 / modulo 1000) in case you have a single dimensional thing. Or you try to solve the problem without storing the state of every light explicitly. 1 million is only many if you waste space.

Comment: For whatever reason, my program would pause at around 7000 Array Objects (note: each object of the array had a 1x3 array in it). I checked my memory and processor and they had both maxed out. I switched to a byte[] and handled coordinates externally (mathematically with a method) and solved my issue. Are ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> extremely bulky or was that not the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.000.000 Objects of each 1kb should take about 1.000 mb or ~ 1gb.

When I read your post I thought

```
 Map <Integer,Lightswitch> = new HashMap <Integer,Lightswitch>();
```

Maybe start with a basic (empty) Lightswitch

```
 public class Lightswitch {
 }
```

and add 1.000.000 of those into the map.

Or (just thinking):

```
byte [] switches = new byte [1000000];
```

And then the byte value represents the lightswitch status ('0', '1', ...)

Answer (score 2):

The most memory efficient way would be to use a `BitSet`, in which case it would take you 1,000,000 bits (or one megabit) of memory (and the obvious additional few bytes) to store the on/off status. The individual bits can be operated on easily with the included methods.

Congratulations on solving your challenge.

Comment: A bitset might be memory efficient, but its extremely slow. storing it in a byte[][] array would only take up 1MiB

Comment: @WalterM Care to back up the "extremely slow" with sources? Especially the "extremely" part. Also my answer did include the clause `The most memory efficient way would be`.

Comment: So I tried a little benchmarking. I found that byte[][] was about 20% faster, and this actually surprises me. I thought surely the BitSet would be faster, because with a byte[][] structure, you have to find the row first, and the row might be null, and each row does not necessarily have the same width.

Comment: @user980717 Did you benchmark correctly? (If you can't say "yes" almost immediately to this question, you didn't). In any case, I wouldn't be surprised if `byte[][]` is faster. JIT can probably optimize it away in a far easier fashion than a BitSet, even though a BitSet would fit into the cache a lot better. It would depend on the usage patterns a lot too.

Comment: The reason I thought byte[][] would be slower is because you must follow two levels of indirection to get to your data element, and you would need to check for a null and a bounds check at each level. And, to compute the row and column of the byte[][] structure, you need integer division, whereas with a BitSet structure, you would just need a shift and mask. In any event, the conclusion is that byte[][] is faster, but not "extremely" faster.

Comment: Did you use a proper test harness? The byte array is probably even faster once you warm up JIT properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just make 2-dimensional integer array of 1000X1000 and fill it with 0's then follow the instructions using file handling. For example for turning on light change 0 to 1.